# Assist or/vs Attend?

Tags: word-usage

Is it correct to say:

> it's very important to assist to the meeting?

Is it similar to say

> It's very important to attend the meeting?

if not, in which context is the word "assist" used?

I read this list of synonyms:  http://www.wordreference.com/thesaurus/assist

As you can see if clicked, "attend" is listed as a synonym for "assist", then, is it correct to use it insetad of "attend" in the sentences above ? or it will be correct/not formal, incorrect, correct/slang ?

That's why I got confuse

Comment: I suggest using the [English Language Learners stackexchange](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) for questions like this in the future.

Comment: In Spanish, ***asistir a** alguna cosa* is attending it, not assisting it.  When you translate to English, you need to choose a different verb than the direct cognate, whose meaning differs here.

Comment: Exactly there is no challenge in your question , I also suggest using the http://ell.stackexchange.com for question like this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are examples of what I believe are known as "faux amies" in French. The meanings are not what you would think based on the related Romance-language words. "Assist" in English means to help. It's not the same meaning as "asistir" in Spanish, which means to attend. "Attend" in English mainly means to be present; its main meaning is not to pay attention (like Spanish "atender"), although it can be used that way in old-fashioned or formal English.

Comment: Then isn't correct, but it's accepted/used ?

Comment: @StoneyB: Thanks for the correction. I've edited the answer appropriately.

Comment: @Allende: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. Both "assist" and "attend" are real English words that are correct, but they don't have the meanings you would imagine based on the analogy with Romance languages such as Spanish.

Comment: @BenCrowell Ohh well the thing is that I saw in the link at the end of the question "attend" is an assist's synonym, you're answer it's quit right I think, you did understand right, I'm just waiting to see if someone else add a comment about why is attend listed as an assist's synonym: http://www.wordreference.com/thesaurus/assist

Comment: Because _attend_ does have a meaning of _look after_, or _take care of_, which can overlap with _assist_. But except in the phrase _attend to_, this meaning is obsolescent.

Answer (score 3):

'Assist' in English does not mean 'attend'. 'To assist' means 'to help'.

In French the verb form 'assister à', means 'to attend'. 'J'ai assisté à la réunion'. It is a classic schoolboy howler in English to translate that as 'I helped at the meeting'.

Answer (score 0):

Attend is the correct word.

You could assist with a meeting.

Looking for grammatical rules why now.

Comment: That was my first idea, but then I read this:http://www.wordreference.com/thesaurus/assist